# What executes textFieldDidBeginEditing on uitextfield within UITableCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, resignfirstresponder

I have a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell (custom cell ).

I have 3 rows in my UITableView. the 2nd row is the text field row. The 3rd row is a link to open another view through an animation block.

The problem I have is if the user is editing the amount and clicks the 3rd row, to forwards to that screen, then when I dismissing this new viewcontroller, the screen goes back to the UITableview controller and fires textFieldDidBeginEditing.

How can I cancel this or avoid the user being sent back into the editing mode? I tried resigning in the table cell and the view controller and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should end the editing of the textfield by calling `[myTextField resignFirstResponder]` when the third row is clicked.

Comment: did this in the willSelect of the custom uitableview     XXXCell* cell = (XXXTableCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
    [cell.CheckAmount resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

Return NO from this delegate method for the field you want to disable editing.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: I tried that, but it introduced to much state handling like asp.et viewstate and was too complicated with multiple screens. Thanks...